# Retain client side use of RequiredFieldValidator when using Script manager

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

Retain client side use of RequiredFieldValidator when using Script manager

I have the following in a asp.net forms (vs2013, net4.5, vb.net)

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
        runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Required text box">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

</form>
```

Above runs just fine and does NOT post back until a value is entered into text box). This is GOOD and makes perfect sense (large numbers of applications use the above approach).

However if I add the script manager control or the  Ajax ToolKit Script manager to the form, then ALL CLIENT side validation RequiredFieldVAlidators STOP using clinet side validation. This is rather large cost for the simple introduction of the script manager into a web form.

So adding this to the above web form is the bad guy:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

The end result is now all EXISTING RequiredValidators NEVER run client side – only server side.

Is there a workaround to the above, namely that of adding the Script manger (or Ajax Tool Kit Manager from the ajax tool kit) to a form and continuing to enjoy client side validation in web forms?

Answer (score 1):

A bit of digging and some BinGoogle I have found the problem.

Unfortunately when using .net 4.5, placing the script manager control into a form will disable client side validation.

The solution is to add this appSettings to the web.config

```
appSettings>
  <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
 </appSettings>
```

The above will force a loss of HTML5 client side validating, but the result is client side validation will return to your forms that use the script manager.